Determinant of $A=(a_{(im),(jn)})$, with $a_{(im),(jn)} = b_{ij} + (1-b_{ii})\delta_{ij}\delta_{mn}$
I have a $NM\times NM$ symmetric matrix, with entries:
$$A=(a_{(im),(jn)})$$
where
$$a_{(im),(jn)} = b_{ij} + (1-b_{ii})\delta_{ij}\delta_{mn}$$
Here the indices $i,j\in\{1,\dots,N\}$, while $m,n\in\{1,\dots,M\}$. In particular, $B=(b_{ij})$ is a smaller symmetric $N\times N$ matrix.
Note that in the matrix $A=(a_{(im),(jn)})$, I use the notation $(im)$ for the pair $(i,m)$, which is then flattened, so that $(im)$ as a flat index traverses the indices $1,\dots,NM$.
I would like to compute $\det A$, which I presume should eventually be given in terms of $\det B$, and some other terms.
So, is there a way to reduce the computation of $\det A$ to $N$-dimensional space and determinants of $N\times N$ matrices, instead of the original $NM\times NM$ ?

I think that if you look at a very simple case, namely when $B$ is diagonal, you can see that the answer depends not just on $\det B$ but also on the other minors of $B$.

@ancientmathematician This is fine, as long as I don't have to deal with the original big size $NM\times NM$. Could you expand on your comment please?

I am thinking about it! But just to make sure: when you write $a_{(im),(jn)}$ you don't mean the product $im$ do you, you mean the pair $(i,m)$?

@ancientmathematician Yes, I mean the pair $(i,m)$. If that's ambiguous I should clarify it in the post.

@ancientmathematician I posted an answer, but I'd appreciate having a second pair of eyes taking a look in case I did something wrong.

I will look later.

The solution you have posted is fine. But let me offer this alternative, which does not involve (overtly) the eigenvectors.
We have an $n\times n$ matrix $B$ and an $n\times n$  diagonal matrix $D$ with $d_{ii}=b_{ii}$. Let $I_n$ be the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Let $J_m$ be the $m\times m$ all-$1$s matrix, and $I_m$ be the $m\times m$ identity matrix. Then $A$ is the matrix $B\otimes J+(I-D)\otimes I$. That is
$$
A
=\begin{bmatrix}
B+I_n-D & B &\dots &B\\
B & B+I_n-D &\dots &B\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
B & B &\dots &B+I_n-D\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The determinant is unchanged by (unimodular) column operations, so that adding into the first block of columns we have
$$
\det A
=\det
\begin{bmatrix}
mB+I_n-D & B &\dots &B\\
mB+I_n-D  & B+I_n-D &\dots &B\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
mB+I_n-D  & B &\dots &B+I_n-D\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The determinant is unchanged by (unimodular) row operations, so that subtracting the first block of rows from each of the other we have
$$
\det A
=\det
\begin{bmatrix}
mB+I_n-D & B &\dots &B\\
O  & I_n-D &\dots &O\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
O  & O &\dots &I_n-D\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
That is,
$$
\det A=
\det(mB+I_n-D)(\det(I_n-D)^{m-1}
$$
as you assert.
Comment. Although I have not used the eigenvectors of $A$ or $B$ I have in fact implicitly used the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $J_m$. The row and column operations above correspond to changing the basis for the $m$ dimensional space from the canonical $f_1,\dots,f_m$  to the usual eigenbasis of $J_m$, namely $f_1+f_2+\dots+f_m$, $f_2-f_1$,$\dots$,$f_m-f_1$ with eigenvalues $m,0,\dots,0$.

Thanks! I think there is a typo in your last equation, it should be $\det(mB+I_n-D)$, right?

I've changed it. I hate typing matrices!

Thanks a lot. I think I like both your approach and mine equally! I have accepted your answer as appreciation for your help.

Mine would work for a non-diagonalisable (and so non-symmetric) $B$ and so is marginally more general I suppose.

That's a good point! However with my approach I was able not just to compute the determinant, but also the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, which also happened to be useful in the application I was considering ;)

I reckon that in general if $u$ is an eigenvector of $B$ and $v$ is an eigenvector of $B+I-D$ then $u\otimes v$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

Let's look at the eigenvectors of $A$:
$$A\mathbf x = \lambda \mathbf x$$
or
$$\sum_{jn}a_{im,jn} x_{jn} = \sum_{jn}b_{ij}x_{jn} + (1-b_{ii}) x_{im} = \lambda x_{im}$$
There are a total of $NM$ eigenvectors.
Suppose first that $x_{im}=x_{i}$ does not depend on $m$. Then the eigenvalue equation gives $M\sum_{j}b_{ij}x_{j} + (1-b_{ii}) x_{i} = \lambda x_{i}$, that is, $x_i$ is an eigenvector of the symmetric matrix $Mb_{ij}+(1-b_{ii})\delta_{ij}$ and $\lambda$ the corresponding eigenvalue. There are $N$ eigenvectors of this class.
Now we consider $x_{im}$ depending on both indices, but orthogonal to the previously found eigenvectors. This implies that $\sum_m x_{im}=0$. Then our eigenvalue equation reduces to $(1-b_{ii})x_{im} = \lambda x_{im}$, that is $\lambda=1-b_{ii}$ and $x_{jn}=\delta_{ij}y_m$ for some $i$, and $\sum_m y_m=0$. There are $N(M-1)$ eigenvectors of this class.
Let $\Lambda_1,\dots,\Lambda_N$ denote the eigenvalues of the $N\times N$ matrix $Mb_{ij}+(1-b_{ii})\delta_{ij}$. We can then compute the determinant of $A$,
$$\det(A) = \prod_{i=1}^{N}\Lambda_i(1-b_{ii})^{M-1}$$
If we denote by $C$ the matrix with entries $Mb_{ij}+(1-b_{ii})\delta_{ij}$, and by $D$ the diagonal matrix with entries $b_{ii}$ (both of them are $N\times N$), we can write
$$\det(A) = \det(C) \det(I-D)^{M-1}$$
