Eigenvectors of a matrix that commutes with subgroup of permutation matrices
I have a certain symmetric matrix $M_{ij}$, that is invariant under certain permutations of some of the indices $i=1,\dots,N$. More precisely, there exists a subgroup of permutations $G$, such that if $P$ is a permutation matrix belonging to $G$, then $MP=PM$.
I would like to exploit these permutation symmetries in the computation of eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $M$.
Clearly there is a connection, since $MP=PM$ implies that $M,P$ can be diagonalized simultaneously. The question, is how to exploit this fact, considering all $P\in G$.
I'd appreciate some guidance in the relevant techniques / theorems / literature, since I suspect this problem has been considered in the literature.
Example: For a concrete example of the arguments I'm thinking of, see this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4937901/10063. This illustrates the kind of argument I'm thinking of, that exploits permutation symmetries in the matrix entries to compute its eigenvectors. However that's just one particular case. I'm asking about a generalization of this approach.

As an example of the kind of matrices I'd like to consider, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4936527/10063

In particular, this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4937901/10063, illustrates the kind of argument I'm thinking of, that exploits permutation symmetries in the indices of the matrix to compute its eigenvectors.

This can be understood in terms of representation theory of finite groups which you can learn about from many sources. Let $V$ be the vector space of column vectors on which these matrices are acting. Under the action of $G$, $V$ decomposes as a direct sum of irreducible representations
$$V \cong \bigoplus_i V_i^{n_i}$$
which implies by Schur's lemma that its endomorphism algebra $\text{End}_G(V)$, namely the algebra of matrices $M$ satisfying $Mg = gM$ for all $g \in G$, is given by
$$\text{End}_G(V) \cong \prod_i M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C}).$$
$M$ belongs to this algebra, which places strong constraints on it depending on what the irreducible decomposition of $V$ is like. Most fundamentally, this decomposition implies that each eigenvector of $M$ must lie in exactly one of the subspaces $V_i^{n_i}$ these are called the isotypic components of the representation. The nicest case is if the representation is multiplicity-free, meaning that each $n_i = 1$; in that case $M$ must act by multiplication by a scalar on each irreducible $V_i$, so every vector in each $V_i$ is an eigenvector.
Moreover it is possible to explicitly write down idempotents which project $V$ onto each of its isotypic components in terms of the action of $G$ and its character table; see e.g. here.
You can see some examples of this kind of argument in this blog post where I apply this idea to $M$ being the adjacency matrix of a finite graph with automorphism group $G$.

Thanks! Yes, this seems to be exactly what I want! However there are a lot of keywords in your answer that I'm not familiar with, and that I would like to understand better. Could you please suggest some relevant references, to study this more deeply?

For instance I don't understand the notation of your second equation, $\text{End}G(V) \cong \prod_i M{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$. What is $M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$? What does $ \cong$ mean?

@a06e: Fulton and Harris' Representation Theory (the bit about finite groups) is probably an okay place to start, depending on your existing background in abstract algebra. $M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$ is the ring of $n_i \times n_i$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$, and $\cong$ means "isomorphic to" (as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra).

Your blog post is very nice! But I start to get lost when you start talking about character, Burnside's lemma, etc. I'm not familiar with these things. I'm reading Fulton & Harris.

In the blogpost, are you using the notation $\operatorname{Fix}(g)=\operatorname{tr}(g)$ to mean the character of the matrix representation of $g\in G$?

@a06e: yes. You'll find characters and Burnside's lemma and stuff like that in any introduction to representation theory of finite groups.
